# Trying to understand JS Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
function btnDisplay_onclick() {
  var age = ageTextboc.value;
  var minWeight = [5, 15,25, 45, 60, 70, 75, 80];

  minWeightTextbox.value = minWeight[age-1];
}
```

I want to know why I need to use `age-1` part in `minWeightTextbox.value = minWeight[age-1];` rather than just `age`.

If someone could help explain exactly what this does, that would be amazing.

Comment: But what does -1 mean exactly? It makes it start at 1 instead of 0? I'm brand new to this sorry if this is a stupid question.

Comment: We don't know what's in your variables, so we can't be much help.

Comment: http://image.prntscr.com/image/1698a6f659304153874b6c4cebb09628.png Will this help?

Comment: Don't link to pictures of the code, put the code in the question.

Comment: Also, please choose a meaningful title for you question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically speaking, you *don't have to do `age-1`, you can just do `age`* ... the gotcha is that you have to enter the age starting at 0 instead of 1. (Assuming your array is accurate for 0 meaning less than one month.)

The reason, as explained in the other answer and comments, is because arrays start at 0 in javascript (and most everywhere else, except for some strange places).

Alternatively, you can add a filler value for the 0 position in the array. Here I've added 1. Now you don't have to use `age-1`, you can just use `age`.

```
var minWeight = [1, 5, 15, 25, 45, 60, 70, 75, 80];
```

Here's another alternative that modifies the array in the same fashion;

```
var minWeight = [, 5, 15, 25, 45, 60, 70, 75, 80];
```

Only this time, the first place that occupies index 0 is undefined.

[Here's some history to read up on.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/110804/why-are-zero-based-arrays-the-norm)

Array indexes are cardinal instead of ordinal. The first (ordinal) place is index 0 (cardinal). Objects can have number members too, but they're nominal.

[Here's a clear explanation.](https://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/cardinal-ordinal-nominal.html) Ordinal for ordering (1st), cardinal for counting (0, 1, 2...), nominal for naming (#3).

Answer (score 0):

It's because arrays are  0 indexed and that code wants to visually represent ages in months (1-9).  So if I select age "1" you are storing the data at index 0.

So minWeight[0] represents the weight for "age" 0.